# JSON to HTML page for name and image as output

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, django-forms

Can somebody help me to get the `Name` with his associated image from the following json.

Code should be in HTML or JS, as I am a backend developer and not able to figure out this.

The JSON:

```
{
"boardMembers": [
{
"id": "18706279",
"name": "Monique R Herena",
"thumbnail": null,
"title": "Chief Colleague Experience Officer",
"slug": "18706279-monique-r-herena",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "19676689",
"name": "Elizabeth Rutledge",
"thumbnail": {
"url": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iABmk_sWUnY4/v3/80x80.png",
"alt": null
},
"title": "Chief Marketing Officer",
"slug": "19676689-elizabeth-rutledge",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "18784925",
"name": "Tangela Richter",
"thumbnail": {
"url": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iKYkW0FlMRW4/v3/80x80.png",
"alt": null
},
"title": "Chief Governance Ofcr/Secy",
"slug": "18784925-tangela-richter",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "15024090",
"name": "Laureen E Seeger",
"thumbnail": {
"url": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iiw0z.pdTRbE/v1/80x80.jpg",
"alt": "LAUREEN E SEEGER"
},
"title": "Chief Legal Officer",
"slug": "15024090-laureen-e-seeger",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "21336581",
"name": "Jennifer Skyler",
"thumbnail": null,
"title": "Chief Corporate Affairs Officer",
"slug": "21336581-jennifer-skyler",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "19676686",
"name": "Raymond Joabar",
"thumbnail": null,
"title": "Pres:Global Risk/CRO",
"slug": "19676686-raymond-joabar",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "15365626",
"name": "Douglas E Buckminster",
"thumbnail": null,
"title": "Group Pres:Global Consumer",
"slug": "15365626-douglas-e-buckminster",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "16654781",
"name": "Anna Marrs",
"thumbnail": {
"url": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iNFzMiuYiRGY/v3/80x80.png",
"alt": null
},
"title": "Pres:Global Commercial Svcs",
"slug": "16654781-anna-marrs",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "16804630",
"name": "Denise Pickett",
"thumbnail": {
"url": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iReOY_ZB0dOI/v2/80x80.png",
"alt": null
},
"title": "Pres:Global Services Group",
"slug": "16804630-denise-pickett",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "6832356",
"name": "Anre D Williams",
"thumbnail": {
"url": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iJ5kSc7LL.3Y/v2/80x80.png",
"alt": null
},
"title": "Pres:Global Merchant & Network Svcs",
"slug": "6832356-anre-d-williams",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "3221610",
"name": "Jeffrey C Campbell \"Jeff\"",
"thumbnail": {
"url": " ",
"alt": "35000014"
},
"title": "Exec VP/CFO",
"slug": "3221610-jeffrey-c-campbell",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "16733751",
"name": "Marc D Gordon",
"thumbnail": {
"url": " ",
"alt": null
},
"title": "Exec VP/CIO",
"slug": "16733751-marc-d-gordon",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "21531045",
"name": "Jessica Lieberman Quinn",
"thumbnail": null,
"title": "Exec VP/Controller",
"slug": "21531045-jessica-lieberman-quinn",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "19863566",
"name": "Alan P Gallo",
"thumbnail": {
"url": " ",
"alt": null
},
"title": "Exec VP:Internal Audit/Chief Audit Exec",
"slug": "19863566-alan-p-gallo",
"webVisibility": true
},
{
"id": "16310906",
"name": "Vivian Zhou",
"thumbnail": null,
"title": "Senior VP/Head:Investor Relations",
"slug": "16310906-vivian-zhou",
"webVisibility": false
}
],
"totalExecutives": 17
}
```

Comment: You can use json_decode php function

Comment: HI Forge, Thanks but can be it in JavaScript or HTML ? can i get sample code for it.

Comment: Have you tried to implement according to specifications and something did not work? If yes please post exactly the problem you experienced.

Comment: Yes, just trying to get name and Image from JSON, but Showing Empty page while running through the code given by Bruno Freire... After parsing JSON it is getting empty.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the front-end world! First, HTML IS NOT a programming language, it is a Markup Language. You need to use JavaScript to do that, not HTML.

You need to parse the string into an object and iterate each "member" on the object list to get this Name and Photo. I wrote a JavaScript version and a PHP version for comparison.

**If you're using JavaScript:**

1. Parse the string into JavaScript object ("JSON.parse" function)
2. Iterate items in "boardMembers" list
3. Get those values

CODE:

```
//Your string 
let stringToParse = '<your string here>'

//Converting your string to object
let convertedToObject = JSON.parse(stringToParse);

//Getting the boardMembers list from your parsed object
let listBoardMembers = convertedToObject.boardMembers;

//Creating Elements on HTML (creating a Paragraph with the received data and a container for the list of members). *Notice: I've created a "DIV" (container) with a unique ID ("listMembers"). This is important because when I start to iterate the members I will add them inside the container, and for that, I need to reference it using an ID.*

document.body.innerHTML = `<p> Received String: ${stringToParse}</p>`;
document.body.innerHTML += `<div id="listMembers"></div>`;


//Iterating the list of boardMembers using this length;
for (let i = 0; i < listBoardMembers.length; i++) {
  let member = listOfMembers[i];

  let memberName = member.name;
  let memberImageURL = '';

  // Verify if the user has thumbnail
  if (member.thumbnail !== null){
     memberImageURL = member.thumbnail.url;
  }


  //Adding this member to the member's container, using the container ID, that we created previously.

  document.getElementById('listMembers').innerHTML += `
     <div style="display: flex;">
       <img src="${memberImageURL}">
       <h1>${memberName}</h1>
     </div>
  `;
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: let stringToParse = "{{models}}";
      document.body.innerHTML = "<h1> string is  " + stringToParse + "</h1>"
      let convertedToObject = JSON.parse(stringToParse);
      let listBoardMembers = convertedToObject.boardMembers;  Till stringToParse is okay.. but after it is going empty page... is there something missing.. ?

Comment: I have been edited the answer to show the members on HTML body.